# Does the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_{0} ^{1} \cos x \, d(\alpha (x))$ exists if $\alpha$ is not of bounded variation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Does the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_{0} ^{1} \cos x \, d(\alpha (x))$
exists if $\alpha$ is not of bounded variation? Justify.

In the Apostol's book, there are two sections "Integrators of bounded variation" and "Necessary conditions for existence of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals", but in these sections I have not found the answer to my question.

Comment: It is a sufficient condition. It's certainly necessary in the sense that you can find an integrand where the integral diverges, otherwise. Whether that may happen with such an innocent integrand as $\cos x,$ is another question. Probably not, but... why do you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral ***can*** exist if $\alpha $ is not of bounded variation.

Since $f(x) = \cos x$ is monotone on $[0,1], \,\, $if $\alpha$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $f$ we have by integration-by-parts

$$\int_0^1 f \, d \alpha = f(1)\alpha(1) - f(0) \alpha(0) - \int_0^1 \alpha \, df.$$

Note that it is not necessary that $\alpha$ have bounded variation -- for example, $\alpha(x) = x \sin (1/x)$ (with $\alpha(0) := 0)$ which is continuous (and integrable).

Comment: I tried to compute the integral: $\int_0^1 f \, d \alpha = f(1)\alpha(1) - f(0) \alpha(0) - \int_0^1 \alpha \, df = \cos (1) \sin(1) + \int_0^1 x \sin(1/x) \, \sin(x) \, dx $, but it is not easy to compute. Can you give me some hint on how to compute it?

Comment: It certainly exists since the integrand $x \sin(1/x) \sin x$ is continuous. Wolfram Alpha finds $\int_0^1 x \sin(1/x) \sin x  \, dx \approx. 0.257419$ which can be obtained numerically.  There is no reason to expect there to be an anti-derivative in terms of standard functions.